# Fine tuning LR in my scenario

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, softmax, learning-rate

I am trying skip gram implementation from scratch (no pytorch or tensorflow, but just NumPy; actually CuPy because numpy does not run on GPU, but CuPy does) I am trying out what should be learning rate. Below is my log and interpretation:

[image]

Another screenshot with LR=0.0001:

[image]

I seems that for some stable LR say 0.1, 0.001 or 0.0001, the improvement in loss per epoch is way too tiny. This means, I have to train for several hundreds of epochs which might be difficult as I am using free Colab GPU and one epoch takes approx 8 minutes.

Are my interpretations correct? What LR should I try out? What else should I try out here?